# Issue on retrieving specific time data using php mariadb

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am new on web development trying to fetch data by particular time of the day from MariaDb database but getting no results.

I am trying to execute sql query from laravel 4 framework. My DB field type is datetime. Please see codes at below:

```
 $today=date('Y-m-d h'); 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM REPORT WHERE SEND_DATE =  '". $today."' ";
 try{
  $rows = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
  return $rows;
  }catch(Exception $e){
      Logs::log_write("Error: " . $e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
```

I am expecting result by particular time of the date or day such 
if I enter value of $today= '2019-09-04 06' than I want fetch all record from DB if value matched.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `SEND_DATE` a DATETIME column, because if it is that code should work

Comment: But you dont seem to be doing a `->get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for MYSQL/MariaDB "DATE_FORMAT" function. Using that function you can format & retrieve particular data. Please try to update your query as below:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM REPORT WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SEND_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %h') =  '". $today."' ";
```

You can get more details about the MYSQL DATE_FORMAT from the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp